# IIS 6 Compression for a folder

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, web-server, iis-6, compression

I want to enable IIS 6 compression for all of the folders in my application except one; in this one folder, I do some things that fails when IIS 6 compression is enabled...

Any advice?  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

So don't compress any of the folders.

Comment: Well, then I don't get the benefit of compression; I would like that benefit, but I  can't figure out how to even enable or disable compression for a single folder...

Comment: Compression has two cons: it slows things down, and some applications break when Windows file compression is enabled.